# How to return multiple images from controller method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image-processing

I have an ASP.NET MVC controller that generates images (they are stored in memory, I don't want to store them on the hard drive) and should return them to my view.

The problem is: I don't how know how to return multiple images from one controller method (I want to show the images in 1 view). I know that I can return a single image with the `FileResult` for example, but I can't find out (not on google/stackoverflow) how to return multiple images from the same method. Splitting the method up in multiple methods can't be done. Oh, all of the images are converted to a `byte[]`, but that can be reversed if necessary.

Comment: Your goal is to return multiple individual images from a controller action? You can't.. you can combine them into a single image though..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have access to the MIME type of the image, you could always render them as Base64-encoded images, instead of making another request to a different controller method. This is a view model I use:

```
public class ImageViewModel
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    public string MIME { get; set; }

    public byte[] Data { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format(@"data:{0};base64,{1}", MIME.ToLower(), Convert.ToBase64String(Data));
    }
}
```

You can use the `Filename` property in the `alt` attribute of the `<img />` tag, so the markup & model-binding in your view would look something like this (assuming Razor syntax):

```
<img src="@model.ToString()" alt="@model.FileName" />
```

You do lose image-caching, AFAIK - that hasn't been an issue for me, but is understandably a deal-breaker for some.

Answer (score 5):

This should work.  Note I am reading my images from disk for my example but they can come from memory or anywhere.  Then on the client side use java-script to display them.

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult Images()
{
    var image1Base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/Images/1.jpg")));
    var image2Base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/Images/2.jpg")));

    var jsonResult = Json(new { image1 = image1Base64, image2 = image2Base64 }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;

    return jsonResult;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that you can solve it in another way, instead of returning multiple images, you can create a utility method that loads the image in the controller

```
public FileContentResult GetImage(int imageId)
{
  var image = GetImageById(imageId); // get from a list for example
  return File(image, "image/jpeg"); // your image Mime type
}
```

and in the `View` you can do the following, iterate over the images

```
@foreach (var image in Model)
{ 
<img alt="" src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "ControllerName", new {imageId =image.Id})"/>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You wish to show multiple images based on input of the user, but don't want to save to the hard disk (chat). Therefor I recommand you using a session variable to save the users input in. And the use a simple `FileResult` to return multiple images based on that session variable.

http://blog.theobjectguy.com/2009/12/session-with-style.html

Comment: Why would you use the session when there are much cleaner ways of doing this?

Comment: Because he doesn't want to write to a folder explicitly and he has to return multiple images (aka multiple http calls) and he generates those images base on an input image of the user.

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to show multiple images in one view it would be easier to use 2 action methods. One that returns a image with FileResult and another where you just use standard html img tags pointing the first action method

Comment: Or a "factory" that accepts a parameter that returns a different image from the same action based on the parameter..